# imagewebp from string converting only white background

Tags: php

Why imagewebp from string converting only white background for my live server? However the same function works for local one and it's converting properly.

```
$temp = explode('.', $fileAbsolutePath);
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileAbsolutePath));

imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

unset($temp[count($temp) - 1]);

imagewebp($image, implode('.', $temp) . '.webp', 100);
```

Comment: likely the `$fileAbsolutePath` variable ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it's a path of image, for example `/var/www/project/public/files/some_image.png`

Comment: if the code is unchanged between local and live servers then the only thing that can be different is this path. Have you confirmed that the image can be read with the given path?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The path is correct. Can the php 7.2 and 7.4 have difference for it? I think no.

Comment: and `var_dump(file_get_contents($fileAbsolutePath));` reveals?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes

Comment: ? do you mean that it shows meaningful data or simply `yes`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius meaningful data. the same data for same image on my local

Comment: I tested the above locally and all seems well on PHP 7.2.9 using an absolute path from local filesystem. File saved correctly and displays correctly though I did modify the output name/path from the above

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius in my local also working properly.